# if / then formula over many rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to produce a code (simple for some) but I am inexperienced and would appreciate help.

Code to look at cell (`"J1"`) and doing an `if / then` for a result in ("`K1`"), but I want to have this duplicated to look at the range  `J2 to J10` cells , to give the result in the range `K2 to K10` cells as well.
The code below works for single row formula:

```
    Sub Check() 
        Dim DDDD As Date, result As String 
        DDDD = Range("j1").Value 
        If DDDD >= Date Then 
            result = "Future" 
        Else 
            result = "Now" 
        End If 
        Range("k1").Value = result 
   End Sub
```

Comment: Excel VBA has been around for a long time. Therefore, the [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx) is actually pretty good. I recommend using the "For Loop" structure.

Comment: Even better: don't use VBA for this, but in-cell formulas.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn, I think your code only covers the J1 Cell, not through to J10.  Appreciate your reply. Shai Rado reply below goes into the loop of the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`For Each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) loop and the [`Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method, like this:

```
 Sub Check() 
    Dim DDDD As Date, result As String 
    Dim cell as Range

    For Each cell in Range("J1:J10")
        DDDD = cell.Value 
        If DDDD >= Date Then 
            result = "Future" 
        Else 
            result = "Now"
        End If 
        ' Change value at the right side of the cell
        cell.Offset(0,1).Value = result 
    Next cell
End Sub
```

But using VBA for this is really overkill. You could just put this formula in `K1`:

```
=IF(J1 >= TODAY(), "Future", "Now")
```

... and then copy/drag that formula down to the other cells below it.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back on the answers given?

Comment: Thanks Andy @trincot really appreciate your updated response . I hit the ticks too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that loops through Column J, and the result will be placed at Column K.

```
Sub Check()

Dim DDDD As Date
Dim result As String
Dim row, NumofRows  As Integer

' use NumfofRows as a Dynamic value to decide how many rows of data you want to look at column J
NumofRows = 10

For row = 1 To NumofRows
    If Cells(row, 10) >= Date Then
        result = "Future"
    Else
        result = "Now"
    End If 
    Cells(row, 11).Value = result
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado, Appreciate your help along with the others who reply to my post.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, take a look at the [rules of etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that make your questions both fun and enticing to answer. For your question, it will be more efficient to deal with Ranges rather than individual cells with dates in them. The `For Each...Next` loop can cycle through each cell in the range. Then, an `If...Then...Else...End If` loop can make a decision given various conditions. The `Offset(0, 1)` method can be used inside the `If...Then` loop to place results in the column to the right. The following code does what you seem to be asking:

```
Sub Check()
'    Declare your variables
     Dim MyDates As Range
     Dim result As String

'    First, grab all the values in the J2:JX column, where
'    X can be any number of dates you choose. Note that
'    you must "Set" Object variables, but you must "Dim"
'    other types of variables. 
     Set MyDates = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))

'    Loop through every cell in the dates column and give the
'    offset column (column K) a string value if the condition
'    is met.
     Dim Cell As Range
     For Each Cell In MyDates
         If Cell >= Date Then
             result = "Future"
             Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
         Else
             result = "Now (or past)"
             Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
         End If
     Next Cell
End Sub
```

The `End(xlDown)` method emulates selecting a cell and pressing Ctrl+Down arrow. Also, note that this code does not handle mistakes at all. For example if you accidentally enter a date as *text*, the procedure will produce an incorrect result. Also, depending on the time you enter data, you could get confusing results. I've attached an image of the results in Excel here:

[image: My results in Excel with Form Control to execute VBA.]

Comment: Thanks Andy, @trincot , I have been given some great responses and really appreciate.  Apologies for not responding sooner, I am overseas on biz trip and just now getting to my personal emails. I am a beginner and find these applications really interesting and of real value in my job.

Comment: It will help the community if you select which response best answer's your question. To the left of the questions is a check mark option. If you select it, that turns green, notifies the community that you voted the best answer, and it gives points to the contributor.

Comment: Hi @Andy , Can you go a step further with the code. I am trying to work out how to adapt your code if I have dates in Cells J2:J100, but only want the formula to apply to Cells J3:J10.....     I tried putting it in your code as J3:J10 without success.

Comment: Hello @quwi, if you want to change the results to calculate based on only `J3:J10`, then you would simply need to change `Set MyDates = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))` to `Set MyDates = Range("J3:J10")`. With additional tweaking, you could even have an InputBox to select the range you desire, thus making it dynamic. If you like this answer, please check the green check box in the upper left hand corner of this answer.